# Mvc base viewmodel render data within layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I have created a base viewmodel that all of my view models inherit from. That part is easy.

All views are bound to a viewmodel (all are inherited from the base view model)

Within the OnActionExecuted method I insert a true/false value onto a property within the baseviewmodel depending on some conditions.

From the view side of things. I have a single layout page that some how I want to be able to read the property's value and render a different partial view based on the value.

Is this possible? I dont want to have to add the code to each of the views but I don't think I should be binding the layout to my baseviewmodel either.

If I can stay away from inserting the value into the valuebag that would be great as I need to be able to access these values anywhere in the application via strongly typed names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you want probably isnt possible because as you call a view from the controller then first the code inside that view is executed and then the layouts code is executed
to achieve what you are doing you can do 2 things
1. make the logic inside the `controller` itself and then render the correct `view`
2.call the layout from the `controller` giving it the name of the `partial view` in some property of the `model` or in the `viewbag`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I quite follow the use case, but rather than trying to render out a partial view, have you thought about nesting your layout pages.

I think you should be able to override the layout in the onactionexecuted, so you can set the layout dependant on the bool and that layout will render only the correct option.

Look here for an example:

[Nested layout pages with Razor](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/164/Nested-Layout-Pages-with-Razor)

HTH

Si